How to increase the last number of 16 digits by 1 on excel sheet?
In excel how to increase the last number of 16 digits by 1 like:
A1 : 1234567890123456
A2 : 1234567890123457
And so on so far.
Thanks for the help.

1234567890123456 cannot be stored as a number in Excel cells because of Excel's implementation of the double floating point data type. See Last digits are changed to zeros when you type long numbers in cells of Excel:

Excel follows the IEEE 754 specification for how to store and
calculate floating-point numbers. Excel therefore stores only 15
significant digits in a number and changes digits after the fifteenth
place to zeros.

Therefore the only way to store 1234567890123456 in an Excel cell will be as text string. However, text strings work in formula calculations by first attempting to interpret text strings that contain only numbers as numbers. So given 1234567890123456 as text in A1, then =A1+1 gets 1234567890123450 + 1 = 1234567890123450... <- stores only 15 significant digits in a number and changes digits after the fifteenth place to zeros.
One way would be using VBA as VBA is able using Decimal data type.
Following VBA Function should work:
Function ADDTOBIGNUMBER(bignumber As Variant, summand As Variant) As Variant
 bignumber = CDec(bignumber)
 bignumber = bignumber + summand
 ADDTOBIGNUMBER = CStr(bignumber)
End Function

Given 1234567890123456 as text in A1, then =ADDTOBIGNUMBER(A1,1) should result in text 1234567890123457.
